# Are questions sometimes hidden from some users but not others?

Tags: support, questions

Today, I noticed a question on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) that was posted almost 24 hours ago. I check The Workplace for new questions several times each day and this is the first time it showed up for me. It has over a dozen answers and an accepted answer.

Here's the timeline of that question: [How can I get a new developer to significantly improve their code?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/160542/timeline).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. The exceptions are:

- You could have ignored a tag (and have chosen to hide those questions instead of merely graying them out). It appeared for you when a tag was edited out (or you chose to longer ignore the tag).
- It was deleted and later undeleted (highly unlikely in this case)
- Stack Overflow has a 'personalized' homepage to match questions you're likely to be interested in (based on your previous activity). Other sites like The Workplace don't have this feature though.

It might be that the question got edited so much that you don't recognize it anymore. Or the question was migrated (there's a banner indicating this).

Comment: user can also view site front page in "active" tab and in this case, the question can simply be buried under older ones that just happened to be [meta-tag:bump]ed more recently. This could be especially the case if they use default option of 15 questions per page